# Find centre of gravity of region bounded between parabolas $x^2=4by$ and $y^2=4ax$

Tags: calculus

Now the point of intersection of these two are $4a^{1/3}b^{1/3}$ which makes calculation quite complex. I suspect there must be easy way or question is wrong.

Comment: Could you remind us of the definition of center of gravity?

Comment: íts volume of revolution divided by area

Comment: I have made a small edit in the title. Check if this is what you wanted.

Comment: @user170039 that's ok

Comment: Center of *gravity* depends on you specifying a gravitational potential function.  Do you mean the centroid instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce functions:

$$y_1(x)=\frac{x^2}{4b}$$
$$y_2(x)=\sqrt{4ax}$$

...and the $x_0$ coordinate of the intersection point:

$$x_0=4\sqrt[3]{ab}$$

Area between two curves is:

$$A=\int\int dA=\int_0^{x_0}dx\int_{y_1}^{y_2}dy=\frac{32 \left(a^{4/3} b\right)^{3/2}}{3 a}-\frac{16 a b^2}{3}$$

"Momentum" of area $A$ with respect to $x$ axis is:

$$A_x=\int\int ydA=\int\int ydxdy=\int_0^{x_0}dx\int_{y1}^{y_2}ydy$$

$$A_x=16 a^{5/3} b^2-\frac{32}{5} a^{5/3} b^3$$

So the $y_C$ coordinate of the centroid is:

$$y_C=\frac{A_x}A$$

$$y_C=\frac{3 a^{4/3} b (2 b-5)}{5 a^{2/3} b-10 \sqrt{a^{4/3} b}}\tag{1}$$

"Momentum" of area $A$ with respect to $y$ axis is:

$$A_y=\int\int xdA=\int\int xdxdy=\int_0^{x_0}xdx\int_{y1}^{y_2}dy$$

$$A_y=\frac{16}{5} a^{4/3} b^3 \left(\frac{8 a^2 b}{\left(a^{4/3} b\right)^{3/2}}-5\right)$$

So the $x_C$ coordinate of the centroid is:

$$x_C=\frac{A_y}A$$

$$x_C=\frac{3 \left(\frac{5 \left(a^{4/3} b\right)^{3/2}}{a}-8 a b\right)}{5 \left(\sqrt{a^{4/3} b}-2 a^{2/3}\right)}\tag{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's try $a=b=1$.  Then they intersect at the origin and $(4,4)$.

Now the area between the two parabolas is $A=\int_0^4(\dfrac{x^2}4-2\sqrt x)\operatorname dx$.

And the volume is $V=\pi\int_0^4((\dfrac{x^2}4)^2-(2\sqrt x)^2)\operatorname dx$.

I leave it to you to compute these integrals, and to generalize to arbitrary $a,b$.